# Problems accessing API with PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, post

I am trying to use an API and I'm trying to do it using PHP. The API Instructions Guide says that i need to post 2 required values and I am doing so, but it is showing no return from the API. I figured maybe I made a mistake with my code. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$host = 'http://my.yrc.com/myyrc-api/national/servlet?CONTROLLER=com.rdwy.ec.rextracking.http.controller.PublicTrailerHistoryAPIController'; 

        $post = array(
            'PRONumber' => '741265596',
            'xml' => 'Y'
        );

        $post = http_build_query($post);

        $ch = curl_init($host);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $return = json_decode($return, true); // we get the token.

        print_r($return);
```

And these are the instructions:

[image]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your response is coming back in XML. You can't use json_decode to process XML.

Comment: @aynber you're right! Silly me. However, I tried printing the response before jason_decode and it also didn't work. It's like I'm receiving no response at all.

Comment: What does `echo strlen($return);` show?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `POST` rather than `GET`?

Comment: @Barmar now it works! It was what aynber said. The json_decode needed to be removed. Thank you both!